# Node Js can't access to server from internet

Tags: node.js

hi first of all I have limited knowledge of network.

1. operating system is mac, firewall is turned off.
2. it works on a local network: http://192.168.1.2:8080 (add to safari)
3. next I got my ip address from google.com "what is my ip"

78.157.xx.xxx, so I tried from internet connect to server like:
http://78.157.xx.xxx:8080 (add to safari), but with no success :(

I have a router and 3 devices, and all these three devices have the same ip 78.157.xx.xxx?

server.js

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res)
                  {
                  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
                  res.end('Hello World\n');
                  })
.listen(8080, "0.0.0.0");
```

Comment: Networking questions like this will fare better on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You need an **open port** on your router to allow a connection in to your home network from the Internet. Then you need to create a port forward from `78.157.xx.xxx:8080` to `192.168.1.2:8080`.

You can get more details about **port forwarding** [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding).

[Here](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/) is a useful guide and resource to configure the router.